# Perl. Install PAR::Packer under Windows (w/ Strawberry Perl)

Tags: perl, module, installation, cpan

I am trying to install PAR::Packer on a Windows system. I tried "cpanm -n PAR::Packer --force" but got the following dump. I don't even understand what it is trying to do in my GnuPgp directory, but apparently there is a problem with blank spaces in its path?
Thanks!

```
Configuring PAR-Packer-1.019
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt: none vs ($;$) at C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 219
Writing Makefile for par.exe
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for PAR::Packer
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Compress::Zlib 1.16 ... Yes (2.042)
Checking if you have Archive::Zip 1 ... Yes (1.30)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.59 ... Yes (6.62)
Checking if you have Getopt::ArgvFile 1.07 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have IO::Compress::Gzip 0 ... Yes (2.042)
Checking if you have PAR 1.005 ... Yes (1.007)
Checking if you have PAR::Dist 0.22 ... Yes (0.48)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Embed 0 ... Yes (1.30)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0.05 ... Yes (0.22)
Checking if you have Win32::Process 0 ... Yes (0.14)
Checking if you have Parse::Binary 0.04 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have Module::ScanDeps 1.09 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have Win32::Exe 0.17 ... Yes (0.17)
Building PAR-Packer-1.019
cp lib/App/Packer/PAR.pm blib\lib\App\Packer\PAR.pm
cp lib/PAR/Packer.pm blib\lib\PAR\Packer.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Obfuscate.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Obfuscate.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PodStrip.pm
cp lib/PAR/StrippedPARL/Base.pm blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Base.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PatchContent.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PatchContent.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bytecode.pm
cp lib/pp.pm blib\lib\pp.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bleach.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bleach.pm
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe par_pl2c.pl my_par_pl < ..\script\par.pl > my_par_pl.c 
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe sha1.c.PL
gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields  -I"C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE"  -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -s -O2 main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:121: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
windres -i winres/pp.rc -o ppresource.coff --input-format=rc --output-format=coff --target=pe-i386
g++ main.o ppresource.coff -s   -s -L"C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\Dwimperl\c\lib"  C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE\libperl514.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbccp32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a -o par.exe
rem
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe encode_append.pl Dynamic.in par.exe Dynamic.pm
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\libstdc++-6.dll > boot_embedded_files.c
open input file 'C:\Program': No such file or directory at file2c.pl line 43.
dmake:  Error code 130, while making 'boot_embedded_files.c'
dmake:  'boot_embedded_files.c' removed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
-> FAIL Installing PAR::Packer failed. See C:\Users\user\.cpanm\work\1406015074.8672\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: It maybe because of your autorun to change the cmd directory. Check it. Also see this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909826

Comment: Thanks for that hint, unfortunately there is no key in the registry that would change my cmd directy, so this did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output, you can see the commands which the Makefile is executing. This one:

```
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\libstdc++-6.dll > boot_embedded_files.c
```

appears to attempt to pass this filename:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\libstdc++-6.dll
```

as a command-line argument, but does not quote it. The called program therefore attempts to open file `C:\Program` and fails. The fault probably lies somewhere within the build process, where a value should have been quoted, but wasn't. You *might* be able to work round it by executing the command correctly quoted:

```
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\libstdc++-6.dll" > boot_embedded_files.c
```

and then rerunning `make` to allow it to build the rest. But this approach is not guaranteed to work.

However, the package seems to be being maintained, with the changelog for the most recent version here:

- http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.020/ChangeLog

and evidence from the bug tracker that some issues are being resolved:

- https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Status=Resolved;Name=PAR-Packer

I suggest you report this bug there, and see whether the maintainers are able to provide a fix.

Comment: I tried running the command you suggested, but it did not work. Apparently, the installer performs some clean-up when it fails, so it is not possible to fix it that way. See below:

C:\Users\user>C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimpe
rl\perl\bin\perl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll "C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub\libstdc++-6.dll" > boot_embedded_files.c
Can't open perl script "file2c.pl": No such file or directory

Comment: In that case, I think you're out of luck, I'm afraid. Do take it to the support website I mentioned above. It certainly looks as if it's a problem which will affect other people, so I'd expect them to be keen to get it fixed.